# Delete all field with autoincrement and reset count

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

There's a way to reset auto-increment field when all rows is deleted from table?

I've noticed if i have 300 rows inside my table, and i execute

```
DELETE * FROM myTable;
```

When i insert new row after delete, auto increment count continue count from last value (also if table is empty. 
It's possible to reset auto increment count when all rows are deleted?

Comment: What happens if you truncate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`TRUNCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html) instead of `DELETE`
Like this: `TRUNCATE myTable;`

It also much faster than `DELETE` (especially on big tables)

Comment: I doesn't know the esistence of TRUNCATE operation, thanks a lot.